# Adding a class-aware global function to a .net web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, scope

When i started working in asp i found it nigh on impossible to leave behind php's good old `echo()` function - my hands literally typed it subconsciously instead of `response.write()`.

So, in .net pages i tend to create something like this:

```
Public Sub echo(ByVal strValue As String)
    Response.Write(strValue)
End Sub
```

And in .net classes (i.e. classes within app_code folder) i tend to create something like this:

```
Public Sub echo(ByVal strValue As String)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strValue)
End Sub
```

Whilst this works fine - i'd like to have this sit at the application level so it can be used anywhere (i.e. within classes, aspx code-behind pages and so on).

Tricky bit comes to classes within app_code i.e. they need to use `HttpContext.Current.` to access the `Response.Write` method.

I know you can have a "Global" function by having it as a shared sub within a public class, but this would still require a double barrel usage (i think?) i.e. `tools.echo()`

**My question:** is it possible to have a global function that wouldn't require the inclusion of a class and if so, how would one make it class-aware, i.e. if it's used within an app_code class then it needs to use `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write` vs code-behind pages that can access `Response` directly.

My bad-habits aside, `echo()` actually looks much neater in code than `Response.Write()` & there are a few other methods I’d like to make global in this manner - hence my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, you cannot create a top-level function.  Eric Lippert, developer for the C# compiler, explains why in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx).

> C# was designed to be a large-scale application development language
>   geared towards pro devs from day one; it was never intended to be a
>   scripting language. It's design therefore encourages enforcing the
>   immediate organization of even small chunks of code into components.
>   C# is a component-oriented language. We therefore want to encourage
>   programming in a component-based style and discourage features that
>   work against that style.

As to your technical question, you have to decide between "can you" and "should you".

**Can you:** My immediate thought would be to use static utility classes or singletons if you have *truly* global, utilitarian methods.  Another "technical" way you could do it is to create extension methods off the `object` type.  **Beware**, the latter reeks of bad practice.

**Should you:** My advice is to do C# things in C# ways.

Comment: Good comments.  I concur about the "scripting language" (anti-goal).

Comment: I thought as much, just have to kick the habit as it where - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Create your "helper" functions to accept the context as a parameter.

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }

    private void LogoutUser()
    {
        Helpers.SessionHelpers.LogoutUser(this.Context);
    }
}
```

and

```
internal static class SessionVariableKeys
{
    internal static readonly string USER_ID = "UserId";
}
```

and

```
internal static class SessionHelpers
{
    internal static void LogoutUser(System.Web.HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Session[SessionVariableKeys.USER_ID] = null;
                    /* or */
        context.Session.Remove(SessionVariableKeys.USER_ID);
                    /* or */
        context.Session.RemoveAll();
        /* and */
        /* icing on the cake */
        context.Session.Abandon();

        /*context.Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx"); */
    }

}
```

Comment: Note, I use this sparingly.  But the above is a "logout" routine that could be call from a few places in the application.